# corrcoef gives nan as output

Tags: python, numpy, nan, correlation

```
  import numpy as np
  print(np.corrcoef([0.594, 0.405],[0.5, 0.5]))
```

Why does this result in  nan ?

One possibility is that, during calculation when expression is divided by 0 variance, it results in nan. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the problem is the division by a 0 variance. You can check this yourself with:

```
a = np.array([[0.594, 0.405],[0.5, 0.5]])

a.std(axis=1)
# array([0.0945, 0.    ])
```

You might instead be interested in obtaining an *unnormalized* version by obtaining the `covariance` matrix instead, which does not divide by the variances nor subtract the mean:

```
np.cov(a)
array([[0.0178605, 0.       ],
       [0.       , 0.       ]])
```